# how to validate the form before submit

Tags: jquery, validation

I wanted to check validation of certain field before submitting a `form`.

```
<form method="post" action="test.do">
  <input type="file" id="file1" />
  <input type="file" id="file2" />
  <input type="file" id="file3" />

  <input type="button" id="submitButton" />
</form>
```

I only want to check validation of `id = file2 & file3`. It should not be left blank.

```
$("#submitButton").click(function() {
     if(validate()){
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    }
   });

function validate() {
    /*  if blank return false else true */
  how to validate here ??
}
```

**Note : ** as I have hundreds of fields to check, it'd be very lengthy to use `id` for validation.

Is there any other way to check ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a class attribute to the validated fields:

```
<input type="file" id="file2" class="validate" />
<input type="file" id="file3" class="validate" />
```

And then do some validation with the jQuery selector: $('.validate')

```
$('.validate').each(function(){
     if($(this).val() == ''){
          return false; 
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var valid = true;
$('input[type=file]').each(function()
    { if ($(this).val() == '') valid = false; }
);
return valid;
```

You may need to do a different check other than val() == ''   I didn't try this out.

Comment: i only want to check certain field e.g. only 2 fields out of 3. so inthat case what should i do?  your solution checks all the available `file type` fields and this is what i don't want to check the all.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
function validate() 
{   
    if(!$('#file2').val() && !$('#file1').val())
    {
        alert('please select file 1 and file2');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your trying to validate empty input fields only why not using:

```
 $(':input').each(function(){
     if($(this).val() <= ""){
          return false; 
     }
 });
```

Comment: can i use any `class` instead of `:input'` ??? this solution would check all the input type field while i only have to check certain fields.

Comment: sure why not. but dont forget to add a class to the element you want to be affected

Answer (score 1):

Hundreds of fields?

Well, because you're using jQuery, I'd suggest the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

The documentation is thorough, and the plugin makes it easy to check multiple fields with almost no setup other than adding classes to the `<input>s`.

If you do want to go into more detail, the plugin also allows you to write custom error messages per field - but that is a little beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: i mean there are 8 to 10 forms and each one having atleast 15 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Give id="form" to form.

```
function validate() {
    var validator = $("#form").validate();
    var isValid = validator.form();
    return isValid;
}
```